# plot two data sets on same chart

Tags: excel, excel-2010, excel-2013, vba

I have a two sets of data that I wish to plot on the same chart in Excel 2013.

The first data set is time series data and has about 100 daily observations. I would like to plot this as a line chart.

The second data set only has 6 data points & I wish to plot these as a column. Is this possible when the number of observation in each data set are different?

I know it can be done if you have the same number of observations in both data sets.

Answer (score 1):

You will make things easier if you give them the same categories and use blanks to skip missing entries.  Excel is not very smart about matching categories between different sets of data unless you are using scatter plots.

[image]